# BlocListener not being executed after Cubit function call

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit

So, I have a cubit with a function that POSTs some data. I have three states, `DataLoading`, `DataError` and `DataLoaded` for my cubit.

When the user taps on a button, I call the function in the cubit. After that, I have a BlocListener to wait until the Cubit emits the `DataLoaded` state. The issue is that the listener is reacting to the state changes.

```dart
Button(
  text: 'Add',
  onTap: () {
    final data = _textController.text;
    
    context.read<PostDataCubit>().post(data);

    BlocListener<PostDataCubit, PostDataState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is DataLoaded) {
          // navigate to another route
        } else if (state is DataError) {
          // show error
        }
      },
    );
  }
),
```

I've tried using `await` on the `read()` call but that didn't work. How do I react to the state changes here? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean that your listener isn't reacting when state is updating ?

Comment: Yeah. There should some action taken when I emit a state but that's not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `BlocListener` isn't listening because you have added the listener inside a function instead of adding it in widget tree. Wrap your button inside `BlocConsumer` widget and it will works fine. Have a look into below code.

```dart
BlocListener<PostDataCubit, PostDataState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
     if (state is DataLoaded) {
          // navigate to another route
      } else if (state is DataError) {
           // show error
       }
    },
   builder: (context, state) {
     return Button(
        text: 'Add',
         onTap: () {
           final data = _textController.text;

            context.read<PostDataCubit>().post(data);
        });
      },
 ),
```